# Is McGee v State of Indiana 131.2 cited in The Verdict a complete fiction?

Tags: united-states, rules-of-evidence, admissibility

In the 1982 movie *[The Verdict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Verdict)* (and, possibly, in the original novel as well), the respondent's lawyer cites "*McGee v State of Indiana*, United States 131.2" (at 1:57:10):

> The admission of a duplicate document in preference to an existing original must presuppose the possibility of alteration so must be disallowed.

Is that case a complete fiction, or is it just that I can't find it?

Did the cited admissibility rule ever exist?

Would something like what happened in the movie happen today i.e. where a witness produces a copy of a document they made, and testifies that the original of it (already adduced to evidence) was tampered with after making the copy, would the copy still be inadmissible?

Comment: There's a McGee vs State of Indiana at https://law.justia.com/cases/indiana/supreme-court/1952/28-705-2.html, but I don't see anything about duplicate documents. Rather, it seems the crux was about whether a defendant could have a confession suppressed prior to trial.